# Are we allowed to talk about our suspensions?

Tags: support

I got suspended a while back, and have changed since then. I don't mind talking about it if people ask, or if it is on-topic to the conversation. However, whenever I talk about *my* suspension, I get the feeling that it is banned, similar to talking about other people's suspensions.

So are we allowed to talk about *our own* suspensions, or does this fall under the aforementioned rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After your suspension is over, assuming that you do not keep doing whatever got you suspended, all is supposed to be forgiven and forgotten.

Moderators will (should) never bring up your suspensions in public since this is considered private information.

Non-moderators should refrain from doing this as well, especially while the affected user is still suspended, as it it isn't nice.

That said, if you want to talk about *your own suspension*, that's fine. I'm not sure *why* you'd want to discuss it publicly, but feel free to do so.

Comment: I can see one reason for wanting to talk about one's own suspension, and that's to warn people "*I was suspended for doing what you're doing, so you would be best advised to stop it*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor yeah don't test bugs with voting on your own account